# How to restrict access to a folder in Apache2

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 4, running as a webserver (using Apache2).
I have a directory that contains images, and I don't want users to access the folder that contains those images via my website, but I want those images still accessible via links. Any ideas?

Comment: apache should have extension or built-in function to access folder with password. BasicAuth.

Comment: Apache documentation: [PasswordBasicAuth](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/PasswordBasicAuth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable the automatic generation of the directory listing (by [mod_autoindex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html), if an `index.html` is missing in the directory), you can disable this feature for your image directory in your Apache config:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/images>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

The files inside the directory will still be accessible via links, image tags, etc., it only forbids the directory listing.

Related:

- [Options Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options) (Apache Documentation)
- [Directory Listings](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/DirectoryListings#DirectoryListings-DirectoryListings) (Apache Wiki)

Comment: Greatly appreciate! Thanks a lot :D